# What is the difference between transport delay and dead time?

Tags: discrete-signals, delay

I am confused on what the difference between transport delay and dead time is. They seem to have the same function, but I'm not sure. Can someone explain the difference if there is one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this document](http://www.multimechatronics.com/images/uploads/mech_n/First-Order%20Process%20with%20Time%20Delay.pdf) (p. 4) and [this one](http://scholarworks.sjsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5034&context=etd_theses) (p. 13), transport delay and dead time denote the same thing: latency.